# Is there any node.js tutorials for implementing restapi and auth using ONLY core modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, restful-authentication, restful-url

I just have a task to implement a simple web server with REST interface and user authorization without using any third-party frameworks but 99% tutorials I can find start with using restify/express/something else. And It's hard to get what is available in the core modules and what functionality could I use to implement what's been reqested (never used node.js before).

**UPD:** Heres what i did if it helps someone: https://github.com/danilaml/SimpleRestServer

Comment: I'd start by looking at how **Express** works. Since you have to use core modules, **Express** would give a good idea how to get started. https://github.com/strongloop/express

Comment: The reason so many focus on libraries and frameworks is because the core `http` module isn't particularly "*friendly*." It's intentionally low-level, only going as far as parsing the request's headers automatically, so many pleasantries you might expect are absent. Parsing the `req.url` to path and query-string, testing the `req.method`, and reading in and parsing the request's body are up to you to implement.

Comment: If you have a professional task to accomplish, I'd suggest using a tried and tested framework to get through it. When you have your own time to contribute to understanding Node.js, "[Node Beginner](http://www.nodebeginner.org/)" is a good book that covers "vanilla" Node.js.

Comment: It sort of testing task and I believe it was implied to use only core modules (thought it's was surprising for me as well/maybe they meant something else) but I have roughly 3-5 days left to complete this task and I don't know how exactly complex should program be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty good. Simple walk through. I'm doing the same thing for an assignment. https://gist.github.com/shimondoodkin/6213581. This is what I have for a POST and 404

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/hello') {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    if (req.method === "POST") {
      console.log('post');
      var body = '';
      req.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data.toString('utf-8');
      });
      req.on('end', function(data) {
        body += data ? data.toString('utf-8') : '';
        var parsedBody;
        try {
          parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
          res.write(JSON.parse({msg: 'invalid json'}));
          return res.end();
        }
        res.write(JSON.stringify({msg: 'hello ' + parsedBody.name}));
        res.end();
      });
    } else {
      res.write(JSON.stringify({msg: 'hello world'}));
      res.end();
    }
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    res.write(JSON.stringify({msg: 'could not find page'}));

    res.end();
  }
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('server started');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't answer the amd auth part. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry to, I only noticed that I wrote amd instead of and >_<.

Comment: Since I asked my question I managed to do something though I'm not really proud of it (was my first attempt at js). Here it is if it helps anyone: https://github.com/danilaml/SimpleRestServer